# fluentd not picking logs from beginning

Tags: docker, supervisord, fluent, fluentd

I am trying to take my docker container logs with fluentd. both application and fluentd process start through supervisord and both are in the same container but fluentd only taking half of the application logs. I need to fetch the logs from the beginning. adding fluentd conf below:-

```
<source>
 type tail
 path /var/log/*
 path_key path
 format none
 read_from_head true
 <parse>
   @type grok
    <grok>
      pattern (?<logtm>%{MONTHDAY}-%{MONTH}-%{YEAR} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} \[%{DATA:thread}] %{GREEDYDATA:message}
    </grok>
    <grok>
      pattern %{GREEDYDATA:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:message}
    </grok>
    <grok>
      pattern %{URIHOST:remote_host} - - \[%{HTTPDATE:request_time}] "%{WORD:method} %{NOTSPACE:request_page} %{GREEDYDATA:message}/%{NUMBER:http_version}\" %{NUMBER:response_code} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{INT:time_taken} %{QS:referrer} %{QS:user_agent}
    </grok>
  </parse>
 keep_time_key true
# time_format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
 tag graylog2.*
</source>
<filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
   logtm ${record["logtm"]}
   thread ${record["thread"]}
   instance "#{Socket.gethostname}"
   namespace "#{ENV.fetch('INSTANCE_PREFIX'){'default'}}"
   app "#{ENV.fetch('APPZ_APP_NAME'){'wordpress'}}"
   level ${if record["loglevel"] == "EMERG";record["level"] = "0" ; record["loglevel"] == "ALERT";record["level"] = "1";elsif record["loglevel"] == "CRIT" || record["loglevel"] == "SEVERE"; record["level"]= "2" ;elsif record["loglevel"] == "ERROR" ; record["level"]= "3" ;elsif record["loglevel"] == "WARN" || record["loglevel"] == "WARNING" ; record["level"]= "4" ;elsif record["loglevel"] == "NOTICE" ; record["level"]= "5";elsif record["loglevel"] == "INFO" ||  record["loglevel"] == nil ||  record["loglevel"] == 0 ; record["level"]= "6";else record["loglevel"] == "DEBUG" || record["loglevel"] == "debug"; record["level"]= "7";end}
  </record>
</filter>
<match **>
 type graylog
 host "#{ENV.fetch('LOG_HOST'){'GL'}}"
 port "#{ENV.fetch('LOG_PORT'){12201}}"
# BufferedOutput config
 flush_interval 5s
 num_threads 2
 # ...
</match>
```

note:- when i change /var/log/* to /var/log/log_file_name.log its working fine.

Comment: Have you tried with `path /var/log/*.log`

Comment: yes, no luck with that too @mchawre

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with a POS file within in_tail

path /var/log/httpd-access.log

pos_file /var/log/td-agent/httpd-access.log.pos

Comment: added but no luck with that too @Gihan Indrajith

Comment: do we need to add pos_file for all log files ?